# Django: HTML form submission

Tags: html, django, http

I am trying to create a simple website, with a form containing 3 options, and when the form is submitted, it displays some text showing the chosen option.

Here is what I have so far...

**myapp/templates/myapp/index.html:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<form method="get" action="{% url submit %}">
<input type="radio" name="which_choice" value="1">Choice 1<br>
<input type="radio" name="which_choice" value="2">Choice 2<br>
<input type="radio" name="which_choice" value="3">Choice 3<br>
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form> 

</body>
</html>
```

**myapp/views.py:**

```
from django.shortcuts import render

def index(request):
    return render(request, 'myapp/index.html')

def submit(request):
    if 'which_choice' in request.GET:
        message = 'The choice is: %r' % request.GET['which_choice']
    else:
        message = 'You submitted an empty form.'
    return HttpResponse(message)
```

**mysite/urls.py:**

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url

urlpatterns = patterns('',
url(r'^myapp/', include('myapp.urls')),
)
```

**myapp/urls.py:**

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url

from myapp import views

urlpatterns = patterns('',
url(r'^index', views.index, name='index'),
url(r'^submit/$', views.submit, name='submit')
)
```

However, I get a "Page not found at /submit" 404 error, when I submit the button from the index.html page. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: When you look at the generated HTML source, how is `action="{% url submit %}"` rendered?

Comment: Thanks - actually, just looking at the generated HTML source helped me to figure out on my own what was wrong. Thanks for the tip!

Comment: I'm glad it worked out. If you think the answer would be useful to others, it is perfectly okay (encouraged, even) to post your own answer so that others can benefit. Enjoy!